# How to invert mask?

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, android-custom-view, paint

I am trying to invert image mask bitmap using below code

```
    static final PorterDuffXfermode eraseMode = new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);

public void invertSelection() {
    Bitmap inverted = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageBitmap.getWidth(), imageBitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    if (!annotationBitmap.sameAs(inverted)) {
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(inverted);
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.drawPaint(paint);
        paint.setXfermode(eraseMode);
        canvas.drawBitmap(annotationBitmap, 0,0,paint);
        annotationBitmap = inverted;
        undoStack.push(annotationBitmap.copy(annotationBitmap.getConfig(), true));
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

after calling this function I am no longer able to draw on annotationBitmap.

What am I doing wrong here???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should read this [beautiful article at medium](https://medium.com/better-programming/practical-image-porterduff-mode-usage-in-android-3b4b5d2e8f5f) 
and i am not sure but i think if you change`PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR` to `PorterDuff.Mode.DST_OUT`
your problem will solve

[image]